# Pass Data to Root View Controller

Tags: ios

I have a simple application with the following structure:

- 'A': Standalone view controller with a WebView
- 'B': Navigation controller
- 'C': Root View Controller in 'B', a TableView of all stores

When the URL of the WebView in 'A' becomes something specific (http://www.mysite.com/store), I need to:

1. Push to 'C'
2. Send a string to be used in 'C'

How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: probably you need to implement the _model-layer_ in you applciation properly, if you have faced such structural issue...

Answer (score 0):

```
Here you can do with delegate methods
```

> // This is your root ViewController to call delegate methods

```
#import "ThirdViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
 @interface ViewController ()<ThirdViewControllerDelegate>
  @end

@implementation ViewController
 #pragma mark -
 #pragma mark ThirdViewController Delegate Method
```

> // Implementation of delegate methods in your Root ViewController

```
-(void)didSelectValue:(NSString *)value{
    NSLog(@"%@",value);
}
```

> ```
> // Pass the last Vc delegate to the next ViewController
> ```

```
-(void)gotoSeconddVc{
    SecondViewController *vc2=[[SecondViewController alloc]init];
    vc2.lastDelegate=self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
}


 #import "ThirdViewController.h"
     @interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
        @property(nonatomic,retain) id <ThirdViewControllerDelegate> lastDelegate;
        @end

-(void)gotoThirdVc{
    ThirdViewController *vc3=[[ThirdViewController alloc]init];
    vc3.delegate=self.lastDelegate;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc3 animated:YES];
}
```

> Implementation of last viewcontroller

```
@implementation ThirdViewController


-(void)btnDoneClicked{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.delegate didSelectValue:strValue]; //call delegate methods here
}
```